# ("svg:rect") element does not appear on the screen when run

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var divElem = d3.select("#svgpathSVGdata");
```

data for squares

```
var jsonsquare = [{
    x: 40,
    y: 170,
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    label: "technology"
    },

    ];
```

setting the canvas with of course width & height declared already

```
var svgcanvas = divElem.append("svg:svg")
               .attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
```

This is the relevant coding... for some reason it doesn't generate a square

```
var square = svgcanvas.selectAll("rect").data(jsonsquare);

circle.enter().append('svg:rect').append("svg:g")
.attr('opacity', 0)
.attr("cursor", "pointer");
}).attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
}).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
}).attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.width;
}).attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.height;
});
```

linking label to the squares

```
svgcanvas.selectAll("text").data(jsonsquare).enter().append("svg:text").text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
}).attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x + 10;
}).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y + 10;
});





</script>​​​​​
```

Comment: I assume that the line `circle.enter()` is a typo and is actually supposed to be `square.enter()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the rectangle's attributes to the group (i.e, `svg:g`) beneath it. In the line below, remove the `.append("svg:g")` and it should work.

```
square.enter().append('svg:rect').append("svg:g")
```

Also, you're setting opacity to zero:

```
.attr('opacity', 0)
```

This makes your rectangle invisible. Set it to 1 instead for full visibility, or some number in between for a translucent fill effect.

Comment: I've set it to 1 & taken it away yet, still no appearance. I have built circles in the same way, but it doesn't work for some reason